# How to iterate over initial dimensions of a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a Numpy array with shape `[1000, 1000, 1000, 3]`, being the last dimension, sized 3, is contains the triplets of 3D spatial vectors components. How can I use `nditer` to iterate over each triplet? Like this:

```
 for vec in np.nditer(my_array, op_flags=['writeonly', <???>]):
     vec = np.array(something)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've addressed this question before, but here's a short example:

```
vec=np.arange(2*2*2*3).reshape(2,2,2,3)
it=np.ndindex(2,2,2)
for i in it:
    print(vec[i])
```

producing:

```
[0 1 2]
[3 4 5]
[6 7 8]
[ 9 10 11]
[12 13 14]
[15 16 17]
[18 19 20]
[21 22 23]
```

`ndindex` constructs a `multi-index` iterator around a dummy array of the size you give it (here `(2,2,2)`), and returns it along with a `next` method.

So you can use `ndindex` as is, or use it as a model for constructing your on `nditer`.